# Combine browser selectors with LESS

Tags: css, less, css-selectors, transition

Is it possible to combine the -webkit, -moz, -o, and -ms selectors into one with LESS?

I tried doing

```
.transition(@t @d) {
    transition:@t @d;
    -webkit-transition:@t @d;
    -moz-transition:@t @d;
}
```

But it broke the css file.

I want to be able to type

.transition(WhatToTransition Duration)

And have it apply to all the selectors.

Answer (score 4):

You could just try putting a comma between the arguments.

```
.transition(@t, @d) {
    -moz-transition: @t @d @e;
    -webkit-transition: @t @d @e;
    transition: @t @d @e;
}
```

And you could also add another argument for the ease and some default values for the arguments, like this:

```
.transition(@t: all, @d: 1s, @e: linear) {
    -moz-transition: @t @d @e;
    -webkit-transition: @t @d @e;
    -o-transition: @t @d @e;
    -ms-transition: @t @d @e;
    transition: @t @d @e;
}
```

I hope this does what you want. And I would also reorder the vendor prefixed properties, to put the non-prefixed property at the end, and you could for example add also `o` an `ms`, as shown above.

so for example. **LESS:**

```
.test {
    .transition(all, 0.5s, ease-in);
}
```

will return **CSS:**

```
.test {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```